# MAC application deactivate when minimise or is in background

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am developing a mac application in which I am showing some count on app icon symbol (Similar to notification count). It work fine when app is in foreground and is active. But as an when I minimise the app or app goes into background. I am not able to see any message count on icon symbol.

```
let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.dockTile.showsApplicationBadge = true
app.dockTile.badgeLabel = String(unrdcount)
```

This method is called when I am getting data from a particular API. Can anyone suggest me how to let a particular API work for infinite time, so that if the application is ON user can get this unrdcount from API.

Comment: From the documentation of `display`, a method of `NSDockTile`: "You can call this method to force the redrawing of the dock tile contents. You might do this if the contents of the underlying application or window change in a way that would require a refreshing of the tile. Some types of system activity, such as resizing the dock, may trigger automatic redraws of the tile. In most cases, however, your application is responsible for triggering redraws."

Comment: and "Cocoa does not automatically redraw the contents of your dock tile. Instead, your application must explicitly send display messages to the dock tile object whenever the contents of your view change and need to be redrawn."

Comment: It is sending message to dock title when any change is their. But when, app goes into background mode or is minimised change is not performed.

Comment: Which version of macOS do you use for testing? Is anything logged to the console? Do you hide the app or minimize the window? Is the method called?

Comment: I am using 10.13, nothing is logged to the console and yes I am minimising the application.

Comment: How do you minimize an app? Is the method called? Is a timer involved?

Comment: Actually, I am new to Mac development but still I try to add different methods in app delegate to check if any of these are called when app is minimised-  "didResignActive", "becomeActive", "didHide" but none of these are called.

Comment: You can't minimize an app. You can hide an app or minimize a window. Do you want to get notified when the app is hidden? Or do you want to get notified when the app isn't the frontmost app anymore? Or do you want to know why the badge freezes?

Comment: I need to know why badge get freezes when I minimise a window or app isn't the frontmost app.

Comment: Is the method called where you change the badge?

Comment: no method is called when badge is changed

Comment: That's why the badge doesn't change.

Comment: Badge doesn't change only if I minimise a window or application hide.

Comment: If the code to change the badge isn't executed, the badge won't change. Find out which code is executed and which isn't.

Comment: Only this code is written and it works fine:- let app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.dockTile.showsApplicationBadge = true
app.dockTile.badgeLabel = String(unrdcount)